# Is there any good way to combine training datasets in torch?

Tags: r, torch

I am trying to combine two datasets then put the merged datasets into dataloader. How should they be implemented in r ？
For instance, if I have two datasets, and I would like to merge them without redefining the datasets.

```
library(torch)
#> Warning: package 'torch' was built under R version 4.1.3
library(reprex)
#> Warning: package 'reprex' was built under R version 4.1.3
load_dataset <- dataset(
  name = "feature",
  
  initialize = function(feaute,labels, n_timesteps, sample_frac = 0.5) {
    
    self$n_timesteps <- n_timesteps  
    self$x <- feaute %>% torch_tensor()
    self$y <- labels %>% torch_tensor()
    
    
    n <- nrow(self$x) - self$n_timesteps + 1
    self$starts <- sort(sample.int(
      n = n,
      size = n * sample_frac
    ))
    
  },
  
  .getitem = function(i) {
    
    start <- self$starts[i]
    end <- start + self$n_timesteps - 1
    
    list(
      x = self$x[start:end],
      y = self$y[start]
    )
    
  },
  
  .length = function() {
    length(self$starts)
  }
  
)

x1 = cbind(rnorm(10),rnorm(10))
y1 = rnorm(10)
dataset_1 <- load_dataset(feaute = x1, labels = y1,n_timesteps = 1,sample_frac = 1)

x2 = cbind(rnorm(10),rnorm(10))
y2 = rnorm(10)
dataset_2 <- load_dataset(feaute = x2, labels = y2,n_timesteps = 1,sample_frac = 1)
```

As code showed, if I want a result as:

```
combine_dataset = dataset_1 + dataset_2
```

Comment: if you just want to stack them, use `rbind()` or `dplyr::bind_rows()`. If they are variables that you want to stack horizontally without a key variable, `cbind()` or `dplyr::bind_cols()`. If there is a key variable to link the two data sets, like a unique ID, there is a collection of `join` variables in dplyr, like `left_join()`, `full_join()`, etc.

Comment: That is to say, should I stack the training data before building the dataset class? Instead of stacking the already established classes

Answer (score 0):

You could write a wrapper `dataset`, eg something like:

```r
library(torch)

dataset_rbind <- dataset(
  initialize = function(x, y) {
    self$x <- x
    self$y <- y
  },
  .getitem = function(i) {
    if (i <= length(self$x))
      self$x[i]
    else
      self$y[i - length(x)]
  },
  .length = function() {
    length(self$x) + length(self$y)
  }
)

x <- tensor_dataset(torch_tensor(1:5))
y <- tensor_dataset(torch_tensor(6:10))

z <- dataset_rbind(x, y)
for (i in 1:10) {
  print(z[i])
}
#> [[1]]
#> torch_tensor
#> 1
#> [ CPULongType{} ]
#> 
#> [[1]]
#> torch_tensor
#> 2
#> [ CPULongType{} ]
#> 
#> [[1]]
#> torch_tensor
#> 3
#> [ CPULongType{} ]
#> 
#> [[1]]
#> torch_tensor
#> 4
#> [ CPULongType{} ]
#> 
#> [[1]]
#> torch_tensor
#> 5
#> [ CPULongType{} ]
#> 
#> [[1]]
#> torch_tensor
#> 6
#> [ CPULongType{} ]
#> 
#> [[1]]
#> torch_tensor
#> 7
#> [ CPULongType{} ]
#> 
#> [[1]]
#> torch_tensor
#> 8
#> [ CPULongType{} ]
#> 
#> [[1]]
#> torch_tensor
#> 9
#> [ CPULongType{} ]
#> 
#> [[1]]
#> torch_tensor
#> 10
#> [ CPULongType{} ]
```